# an incomplete vector space or not a vector space at all

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

So, for exemplifying an incomplete vector space, I have a handout that says, Let's consider a space $\mathbb{V}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ comprising of vectors of infinitely many zeros as their components. Such that if $|x_i\rangle$ is a basis I select on $\mathbb{V}$, then$$|x_i\rangle=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\0\\.\\.\\.\\1\\0\\0\\.\\.\\\end{matrix}\right)$$ the $\text{i}^{th}$ component is 1 and the rest all are zero. My question is, isn't this a contradiction to the definition of a vector space in itself? Because as far as I know $|x_i\rangle \in \mathbb{V}$, but $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}|x_i\rangle \not\in\mathbb{V}$. This I think is in contradiction to the first axiom of a vector space, $$\forall|a\rangle,|b\rangle\in\mathbb{V}, \alpha|a\rangle+\beta|b\rangle \in \mathbb{V}$$. So I would argue that, my space $\mathbb{V}$ is not a vector space by definition, or am I mistaken somehow?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you define instead $\;V\;$ as the set of all "infinite vectors" with all its components *except perhaps only a finite number of them* zero , then you do have a vector space with the usual componentwise operations.

Comment: @Don Antonio: But then if I take two vectors, let's say in $|v_1\rangle \in V$ I have all components equal to 1 but the last one(which is zero). Similarly in $|v_2\rangle \in V$ I have all components 1, but the second last one (equal to zeo). Then, $|v_1\rangle +|v_2\rangle \not\in V$, since none of the components of the resultant added vector is zero.

Comment: I really don't understand what you say: what "last component" are you talking about in your examples, in how is that related to my past comment?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I was basically wondering whether, I could find two vectors $|v_1\rangle, |v_2\rangle \in V\quad :\quad |v_1\rangle + |v_2\rangle \not\in V$. I think, I can't find one and that my previous comment was a misleading one. I will try to find one and if I do, I will message again.

Comment: @ub Robert's answer perfectly well shows this. Isn't it clear?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes but Robert's vector space(is my vector space which is the set of vectors with infinitely many components as zeros), while the $V$ I was talking about with you is your definition of $V$, which denotes the set of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ vectors, such that only a finite number of components are non-zero. The vector spaces are different. So, I was trying to prove that your $V$ might not comprise a vector space, but I am unable to do so as of yet.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Basically your space is a subset of Robert's/My vector space.

Comment: @Ub Nop. Mine **is** a vector space, yours is only *a set*. Of course, as sets, mine is a subset of yours.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Exactly, I understand now. Thanks for the insight and taking the pain for this discussion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector space axioms allow finite sums, but not infinite sums.  The reason the vectors with infinitely many zero components do not form a vector space is
that you can take the sum of two of them and get something not in the space, e.g. $$ \pmatrix{1 \cr 0 \cr 1 \cr 0 \cr . \cr . \cr  . \cr} + 
\pmatrix{0 \cr 1 \cr 0 \cr 1 \cr . \cr . \cr . \cr} = 
\pmatrix{1 \cr 1 \cr 1 \cr 1\cr . \cr . \cr . \cr} \notin V$$

"Complete" or "incomplete" are not properties of a vector space, they are properties of a 
topological vector space (in particular a normed vector space).  Are you sure the handout wasn't talking about vectors with **all but finitely many** components $0$, rather than just infinitely many $0$, and some particular norm?

Comment: What is the difference between a topological vector space and a vector space? No, I'm sure about it, since they are trying to prove to me the concept of Hilbert spaces

Comment: @ubuntu_noob : In a Hilbert space $H$ (particular case of topolgical vector space) we have defined a distance, and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x_n$ with $x_n\in H$ has sense if the series converges in $H$.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob The difference is that one has a topology defined on it, and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Algebraically $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}|x_i\rangle$ has no sense. We only work with finite iterations of the operations. Another thing is if we define a metric structure, as we do (for example) with normed spaces.